# How to apply decidable when they are known?

Tags: agda

I'm trying to prove that binary sort tree insertion. I'm in the middle of the proof and the environment look like this:

```
  -- new rx : ℕ

  Goal: SortedTree (node leaf x (node (insertTree new rl) rx rr))
  Have: SortedTree (insertTree new (node rl rx rr) | new ≤? rx) 
  ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  new≤rx : new ≤ rx
```

Note the `| new ≤? rx` which AFAIK means "I need to know value to reduce it further"

How do I apply new≤rx?

insertTree is defined like this:

```
  insertTree : (a : ℕ) →  (t : Tree ℕ) → Tree ℕ
  insertTree a (node l x r) with a ≤? x
  insertTree a (node l x r) | yes p = node (insertTree a l) x r
  insertTree a (node l x r) | no ¬p = node l x (insertTree a r)
```

I know the value of  new ≤? rx (it's `yes new≤rx`), in fact I `with`ed by `new ≤? x` right now:

```
  ... | no  ¬n≤x with new ≤? rx
  ...        | yes new≤rx = {!proof⟦insertTree⟧ (node rl rx rr)  (sorted-rhs st) new !}
  ...        | no  p = {!!}
```

So how can I tell agda that value of `new ≤? rx` is known and it should go with
`insertTree a (node l x r) | yes p = node (insertTree a l) x r`?

I tried to use rewrites

```
             where prf : (new ≤? rx ≡ yes new≤rx) → SortedTree (node (insertTree new rl) rx rr)
                   prf p1 rewrite p1 = {!proof⟦insertTree⟧ (node rl rx rr)  (sorted-rhs st) new !}
```

But even though I have `p1 : new ≤? rx ≡ yes new≤rx`, agda ignores it and says that I have `SortedTree (insertTree new (node rl rx rr) | new ≤? rx)`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to got it with inspect + rewrite.

```
       proof⟦insertTree⟧ (node leaf x (node rl rx rr)) st new with new ≤? x 
       ... | yes p = st-node (empty new) (sorted-rhs st) p (st-cmp-rhs st)
       ... | no  ¬n≤x with new ≤? rx |  inspect (_≤?_ new) rx
       ...               | yes p | PropEq.[ eq ] = {!!}
              where prf : (new ≤? rx ≡ yes p) →  SortedTree (insertTree new (node rl rx rr)) → SortedTree (node (insertTree new rl) rx rr)
                    prf p0 p rewrite p0 = p
```

Note that `prf` subproof accepts `p` of type `SortedTree (insertTree new (node rl rx rr))` and return the `p` itself, but thanks to rewrite, returned type is changed.